# Get data with AJAX and save them as variables

Tags: ajax, variables

I'm totally new to AJAX and I don't seem to know the best way to search what I'm looking for. So trying to explain it here.
I have a table which lists my users. I want to be able to edit any row of the table without refreshing. So I added a button for each row, by clicking which you'll be able to edit that user with the help of Bootstrap modals.

There's this button which initiates the action:

```
<span class="updateInfo" user-id="<?php echo $users_array['id']; ?>" data-target=".editInfo" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ></i></span>
```

**$users_array** is an array fetched earlier from a table in database. The table also has **'id, name, email, phone'** as columns.

So, what I basically have in my JS code is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.updateInfo').click(function(){
        var userID = $(this).attr('user-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "edit.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                selected_user_id: userID,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // I don't know what to do here :(
            }
        });
    });

});
```

The codes included in **edit.php** file are as followed:

```
$user_id=$_POST['selected_user_id'];

$get_user=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'");
$user_array=mysql_fetch_row($get_user);

echo json_encode($user_array);
```

I didn't put the codes that establish database connection and the like, since they're basics and work fine.

I have several problems here:

1. I have no idea if the way I've written the code so far is correct.
2. How I'm supposed to get those results and save them as variables for a later use.
3. I don't know if I can use the newly created variables as placeholders or pre-defined values in a modal that exists in the original file.

P.S: The modal has a simple form with simple inputs for name, email and phone number:

```
<div class="modal fade editInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myNote" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
<form method="POST">
    <input name="fullname" value="" />
    <input name="email" value="" />
    <input name="phone" value="" />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- set Id for each html element

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    

 $("#fullname").val("USer One ");
               $("#email").val("User@gmail.com");
               $("#phone").val("987654");
               
               
               
     $('.updateInfo').click(function(){
            var userID = $(this).attr('user-id');
            $.ajax({
                url: "edit.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    selected_user_id: userID,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
               $("#fullname").val(data.fullname);
               $("#email").val(data.email);
               $("#phone").val(data.phone);
                }
            });
        });        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade editInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-abelledby="myNote" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
  <form method="POST"> <input id="fullname" name="fullname" value="" /><input id="email" name="email" value="" /> <input id="phone" name="phone" value="" /> </form>
</div>
```

and then bind like this :

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, that **data.email** equals to the same **$user_array['email']** as specified in php file? I also tried `success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     alert(data.email);
    }` But that didn't show any alert.

Comment: Also I don't see anything in the last box (after you said _and then bind like this :_)